# Strange issue with php $_POST

Tags: php, variables, post, encryption

Recently, I've came across very strange issue with $_POST method. When I was running it on xampp on localhost everything was working very well. Now, when I run it on remote VPS variables are not passed via $_POST. When I try to retrieve a variable like:

```
$contacts = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['contacts']);
```

It will neither show when I echo it or var_dump. It also does not want to go into the database. Only after the variable is encrypted either by encrypt or encrypt2 functions it goes to database and is also displayed when I echo or var_dump it.

```
function pad($data, $size) {
    $length = $size - strlen($data) % $size;
    return $data . str_repeat(chr($length), $length);
}
function unpad($data) {
    return substr($data, 0, -ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]));
}

function encrypt($data) {
$key = "keykeykeykeykey1";
$iv_size = 16; 
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size, $strong);
$encryptedData = openssl_encrypt(pad($data, 16), 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$joinedData = hex2bin(bin2hex($iv).bin2hex($encryptedData));
$encodedJoinedData = base64_encode($joinedData);
return $encodedJoinedData."\n"; 
}

 
 function encrypt2($data) {
$hashed = md5($data);
return $hashed; 
}
```

Of course `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}` does not work also.

Comment: you have created the db connection BEFORE trying to access it using `mysqli_real_escape_string` presumably?

Comment: yes i created db connection first, later i accessed it using mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: $contacts = $_POST['contacts']; also does not work so it is not the issue

Comment: and what does `var_dump( $_POST );` or `print_r( $_POST );` yield?

Comment: it gives array(0) { }

Comment: hard to know without your code - the snippets above are not really relevant to the problem

Comment: Well, everything works in localhost so the problem must be in the lines which I've sent

Comment: Or maybe tell me what part of my code would you like to see

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`? This function is useless. You should be using parameterized queries. What does it all have to do with encryption and saving into the database?